# Suggestions for chat system schema design

Tags: sql-server, schema, chat

I need a suggestion about sql table schema. I've opened a table and named it Chats, would it be better for me to add two columns(like ID and Messages) or one that will contain the IDs and the messages? And which one of them will work faster

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column. `id` should only contain **one** number.  And `message` should only contain **one** message.

Comment: I've done that but they both work slow, even there are three or four rows

Comment: What database are you using? MSSql? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: Database tables need normal forms therefore you need to use first variant.

Comment: @Ravshanjon What do you mean slow? It's basically the same amount of data, it can't vary that much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd model this as two tables:

```
Chats
 - ID
 - Name

Messages
 - ID
 - ChatID
 - Message
 - SentDate
```

There should be a foreign key from Messages.ChatID to Chats.ID.

Otherwise you're going to have to create duplicate chats each time someone sends a message.

I would strongly recommend against keeping IDs and Values in the same column, it makes it near impossible to join on and will create all sorts of problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a single column. Add as many columns as possible, each with its own data type because you will be  able to filter and sort the table by each column later. You will also be able to add constraints, indexes, statistics, etc... if needed.

Any query performed on that table will work faster if you use separate columns.